PySpark unpivot or reduce
I have the following dataframe:
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [
        ("D1", "D2", "H1", None, None),
        ("D1", "D2", "H1", "H2", None),
        ("D1", "D2", "H1", "H2", "H3")
    ],
    ["Dimension1", "Dimention2", "Hierarchy1", "Hierarchy2", "Hierarchy3"]
)


I want to transform it so that it becomes something like this instead:
new_df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [
        ("D1", "D2", "H1"),
        ("D1", "D2", "H2"),
        ("D1", "D2", "H3")
    ],
    ["Dimension1", "Dimention2", "Hierarchy"]
)


The logic being:
whencondition = when((col("Hierarchy1").isNotNull()) & (col("Hierarchy2").isNull()) & (col("Hierarchy3").isNull()), lit("H1")).when((col("Hierarchy1").isNotNull()) & (col("Hierarchy2").isNotNull()) & (col("Hierarchy3").isNull()), lit("H2")).when((col("Hierarchy1").isNotNull()) & (col("Hierarchy2").isNotNull()) & (col("Hierarchy3").isNotNull()), lit("H3")).alias("Hierarchy")

display(df.select("Dimension1", "Dimention2", whencondition))

There can be of course be any number of hierarchy columns, but in the end output I only want there to be one column to show what level of hierarchy that record is at.  I started off by creating a list
hierarchies = ["Hierarchy1", "Hierarchy2", "Hierarchy3"]

and got as far as this:
when(reduce(lambda x, y: x & y, [(col( "`" + x + "`").isNotNull()) if x in hierarchies[:i+1] else (col( "`" + x + "`").isNull()) for x in hierarchies]), lit(hierarchies[i]))

which works for i < len(hierarchies), but not any further unfortunately

Try this-
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import expr, array, explode, col

# Stack and explode the columns to get distinct hierarchy values
stacked_df = df.selectExpr(
    "Dimension1",
    "Dimension2",
    "stack(3, 'Hierarchy1', Hierarchy1, 'Hierarchy2', Hierarchy2, 'Hierarchy3', Hierarchy3) as (HierarchyOrder, Hierarchy)"
).select("Dimension1", "Dimension2", "Hierarchy")\
    .filter(col("Hierarchy")\
            .isNotNull())\
                .distinct()\
                    .orderBy("Hierarchy")

# Show the resulting DataFrame
stacked_df.show()


You can create a UDF to generate the Hierarchy value:
def get_hierarchy(*cols):
    for col in reversed(cols):
        if col is not None:
            return col
    return None

get_hierarchyUDF = F.udf(get_hierarchy, StringType())

hierarchy_columns = [F.col(x) for x in df.columns if x.startswith("Hierarchy")]
new_df = df.withColumn("Hierarchy", get_hierarchyUDF(*hierarchy_columns))
new_df.select('Dimension1','Dimension2','Hierarchy').show()

